# update textview in activity from Fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, textview

How to update `TextView` in Activity A from `DialogFragment` ?

in my case, after click the close button in `DialogFragment`, i need to call the method that can change `TextView`

this is method from `Activity`:

```
public void setCountText(String text){
    CountItem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_numOfItem);
    CountItem.setText(text);
}
```

Onclick Button in `DialogFragment`:

```
View.OnClickListener closeHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        new menufeedActivity().setQountText(getCount);


        InfoOrderDialog.this.dismiss();

    };

};
```

Anyone know how to solve this?

```
04-29 03:08:17.513: E/AndroidRuntime(1738): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-29 03:08:17.513: E/AndroidRuntime(1738): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-29 03:08:17.513: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1744)
04-29 03:08:17.513: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at com.example.android.rssfeed.menufeedActivity.setQountText(menufeedActivity.java:169)
04-29 03:08:17.513: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at com.example.android.rssfeed.InfoOrderDialog$2.onClick(InfoOrderDialog.java:110)
04-29 03:08:17.513: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3110)
04-29 03:08:17.513: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:11928)
04-29 03:08:17.513: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-29 03:08:17.513: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-29 03:08:17.513: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
04-29 03:08:17.513: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4025)
04-29 03:08:17.513: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-29 03:08:17.513: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
04-29 03:08:17.513: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
04-29 03:08:17.513: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
04-29 03:08:17.513: E/AndroidRuntime(1738):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can call it like this:

Replace:

```
 new menufeedActivity().setQountText(getCount);
```

With:

```
((menufeedActivity) getActivity()).setCountText(getCount);
```

Answer (score 12):

Just do this.

```
TextView textview = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.yourtextview);
textview.setText("text");
```

Answer (score 3):

In kotlin

```
val textview = activity!!.findViewById<View>(R.id.textView) as TextView
        textview.text = "your_text"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Fragment: call getActivity().startActivityForResult - Method before you finish and catch it in your activity which hosts the fragment with:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

//your method to update textview
setCountText();

}
```

Edit: I found a better solution for you. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15121529/2245646